# Saudia Direct Airside Transit Checked Baggage

Tags: transit, luggage, saudi-arabia, connecting-flights, saudi-airlines

I shall be making a stopover of 10hours at Jeddah, while using connecting flights, both on Saudi Airlines.

What would happen to my checked-in luggage in this period? Do I have to collect it at Jeddah?

Answer (score 1):

If the trip is in a single booking, you do **not** need to collect the luggage. It gets automatically transferred to your connecting flight, so you only have to go to the next gate.